# Reset the view after changes android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I followed a concept of Drag and Drop from [Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/).

In my case, I want to reset the position of image to back to same after successful drop.

I want to count the number of drops happening there. But I am unable to reset it to previous position for next drop.

I am very thankful for your favor. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your `OnDragListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add OnDragListener to parent View.
E.g.
I have a GridView filling whole screen and a grid of ImageView's inside.
When I drag and drop any of ImageView over the other ImageView I'm doing my some action, BUT when I drop this ImageView over the blank place/the background, gridview's OnDragListener get's ACTION_DROP event, and for me this code is useful:

```
gridview.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
              int action = event.getAction();
              switch (action) {
                  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                      if (event.getLocalState() == v)
                          return false;
                      else {
                          ImageView view = (ImageView) event.getLocalState();          
                          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      }
                      break;
                  default:
                      break;
              }
              return true;
      }
});
```